# Definition of Passiversatzform

Tags: grammar, passive

Wenn man Informationen zu Passiversatzformen sucht, findet man verschiedene Definitionen bzw. Auflistungen, was denn nun alles darunter zu zählen sei. Konsens scheint jedoch einerseits zu sein, dass:

> Die Tür lässt sich nicht öffnen.

eine ist, und

> Die Tür geht nicht auf.

nicht, obschon beide im Kern das Gleiche sagen.

- Gibt es einen nachvollziehbaren Grund, warum das Zweite keine ist?

Des Weiteren scheint mir der Begriff insgesamt problematisch. Ist zum Beispiel folgender Satz noch eine P-Form?

> Die Katze lässt sich nicht streicheln.

Und wenn ja, was ist dann mit diesem:

> Der Mann lässt sich nicht ärgern.

- Gibt es eine sinnvolle Definition von Passiversatzformen oder ist es nur ein Terminus, der einfach schick klingt, bei dem aber keiner weiß, was genau es eigentlich ist.

Comment: Ich gebe zu, den Terminus "Passiversatzform" noch nie gehört zu haben. Es ist jedoch relativ einfach, warum "Die Tür geht nicht auf" aus der Reihe fällt; Bei allen anderen Beispielen könntest du fragen "von wem?", also "Von wem lässt sich die Katze nicht streicheln? " / Tür nicht öffnen etc. Beim Satz "Die Tür geht nicht auf" geht das nicht.

Comment: @Saiph... der Begriff ist glaube ich auch nur in der DaF-Szene relevant. Da aber dafür umso mehr. Überzeugende Begründung übrigens. Teil 1 ist quasi beantwortet.

Comment: @Emanuel: DaF = Deutsch als Fremdsprache?

Comment: @hellcode... ja genau

Answer (score 4):

"Passiversatz" ist kein Standardbegriff der deutschen Grammatik und wenn jemand diesen vagen Begriff verwenden will, müßte er erst definieren, was er darunter verstehen will.

Übrigens sehe ich keinen Zusammenhang zwischen Passiv und einer Verbkonstruktion mit lassen und Infinitiv.

-Das Haus wurde modernisiert. 
Wie will man dieses Passiv irgendwie mit "lassen" ausdrücken?

Comment: Bei "lassen" geht es um das Passiv mit Modalverb "können"... "Das Haus kann noch renoviert werden" "Das Haus lässt sich noch renovieren"

Comment: Ich habe so was noch nie als etwas angesehen, das etwas mit Passiv zu tun hätte. Nach meiner Meinung betreibt man mit Begriffen wie "Passiversatz" reine Begriffsverwirrung.

Comment: Seh ich genauso...

Answer (score 3):

Aus dem Namen lässt sich zweierlei herleiten:

- Das (grammatikalische) Subjekt des Satzes handelt nicht selbst, sondern es ist/kann Gegenstand einer Handlung sein. Stichwort *passiv*.
- Grammatikalisch liegt aber keine gewöhnliche Passivkonstruktion vor `Partizip II + Personalform von werden bzw. sein beim Zustandspassiv`. (Sonst könnte man ja *-ersatzform* weglassen.)

Wie Saiph schon treffenderweise angemerkt hat, kann man bei passiven Konstruktionen mit *Von wem?* oder diversen Präpositionaladverbien das Agens erfragen, was beim zweiten Beispiel eben nicht möglich ist.

Andererseits kann man bei der nicht umgangssprachlichen Version des zweiten Beispiels

> Die Tür ist nicht aufmachbar.

nach einem Agens fragen kann. Sich etwas natürlicher anhörend:

> Von wem ist die Krankheit heilbar?

[Hier](http://www.upf.edu/materials/factii/alemany/itin8/Passiversatz.htm) und [hier](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/passiv/passiversatzformen-alternativen-zum-passiv-mit-modalverb/) zB werden solche Konstruktionen dazugezählt. Bei den "Großen" (zB Wikipedia) fand ich interessanterweise nichts dazu.

Es scheint, als könnte man sich sowohl für als auch gegen eine Bezeichnung als Passiversatzform entscheiden. Ich persönlich würde den Lernenden empfehlen, einerseits das "gewöhnliche" Passiv zu lernen, und andererseits die Konstruktionen mit *lassen* oder Adjektiven auf *-bar* usw. einfach als solche zu lernen.